# Azure CDN with shared hosting server

Tags: asp.net, azure, shared-hosting, azure-cdn

I have recently started using Azure CDN for a web app hosted on Azure under the "Standard" Service plan. CDn was working great and page loads dramatically decreased. For some reasons, I needed to shift the web app from Azure to a shared hosting provider and I notice that CDN is not helping much with the page speed as it used to do when the web app was hosted on Azure. Are there any changes that need to be made to make Azure CDN work with shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried testing with a different CDN provider to see if you still experience the same slow speeds while using shared hosting? This could help further narrow down the issue of wether it is CDN or origin server related.

KeyCDN for example offers a variety of [integration options](https://www.keycdn.com/support/section/integration-guides/) that may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the link @CodyA, will try this and let you know if this works :)

Comment: this has been working better than Azure so far :) Still want to know the answer, but will mark this as answer for others to try out :)

Answer (score 1):

We would need to know much more about the characteristics and examples of the performance decrease that you are seeing to be able to provide directed feedback. Overall the network paths between the CDN POPS and the Azure data centers are optimized so it is possible that by switching to an origin outside of Azure you are losing this optimization. This could be most noticeable if you have a lot of long tail content that requires the CDN to make frequent requests to your origin to fill CDN POP's caches. Once the content is cached on the CDN you shouldn't expect to see a difference in performance. You can use the load capability from the Azure Portal or CDN API's to instruct the CDN to load content on the CDN POP's prior to client requests to help isolate if this is an origin issue or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please guide me towards a link on setting up Load capability or using CDN API?

Answer (score 1):

Load Rest API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634451.aspx

c# SDK for Load: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AutoRest/src/ResourceManagement/Cdn/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn/Generated/EndpointsOperations.cs#L1689

You can setup C# sdk using nuget